# understanding python dictionary sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand dictionary sorting in python and I am stumped by this perplexing issue (I am sure it is something dumb but I am nt able to decode the problem).

So I have this nested dict:

```
some_dict={'10_key0': {'pass_fail': 1, 'scoring': 94}, '10_key1': {'pass_fail': 0, 'scoring': 38}}
```

I now try and sort like so:

```
>>> sorted(some_dict, key=some_dict.get('pass_fail'), reverse=True)
['10_key1', '10_key0']
```

I dont understand the output - I would have thought it should be:

```
['10_key0', '10_key1']
```

Is this not the case? What am I missing?

Comment: The `key` argument should be a function. `some_dict.get('pass_fail')` returns `None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `key` is off here. `some_dict.get('pass_fail')` evaluates to `None`, so your call is essentially equivalent to `sorted(some_dict, key=None, reverse=True)`, which is the same as not passing a `key` at all. You mean to pass a function that looks at the current element being considered:

```
key=lambda k:some_dict[k]["pass_fail"]
```

Comment: thank you so much. One day, I will quit programming - I am clearly terrible at it :(

Comment: "Learning Never exhausts the Mind .... "   - Leonardo da Vinci.  Never give up... we're all have been there one time.  ;-)

Comment: @JohnJ Don't give up! You _will_ learn, and you will be thankful you did. Everyone is a beginner at everything they do at some point, and everyone is human and therefore makes mistakes. I highly encourage you to continue programming! :-)

Comment: @DanielHao and Sylvester Thank you for the kind words :( I will try and put more effort in.. unbeleivable that I did not catch this :(

Comment: @JohnJ No problem. And answering this question earned me my Python Gold Badge, so thank you for asking it :)

Comment: @Carcigenicate thats great news. Thank you again for helping me. You are worth Gold :)